# Нахождение индекса строки по ее порядковому номеру

Tags: python, pandas

Есть два датафрейма, у которых индексы не по-порядку и даже возможны пропуски в последовательности индексов.

Нужно найти все индексы строк обоих фреймов, которые удовлетворяют определенным условиям.

Часть моего кода:

```
for i in range(negative.shape[0]):
    for j in range (data.shape[0]):
            if negative.iloc[i]["CustomerID"] == data.iloc[j]["CustomerID"] and 
            negative.iloc[i]["StockCode"] == data.iloc[j]["StockCode"] and 
            negative.iloc[i]["Quantity"] == -data.iloc[j]["Quantity"]:
            n.append(())
```

и вот в переменной `n` я хочу получить кортежи из индексов строк, в которых условие выполнилось. То есть, как вариант `n: [(234,564),(22,643),и т.д]`

А вот подготовил срез данных:

```
a = {"Invoice":['C536383','C581484','C541433','C536391','C536391','C581490','C581568','C581569'],
 "StockCode":['35004C','23843','23166','22556','21984','23144','21258','20979'],
 "Quantity":[-1,-80995,-74215,-12,-24,-11,-5,-5],
 'CustomerID':[15311,16446,12346,17548,17548,14397,15311,17315]}
negative = pd.DataFrame(data=a, index=[154,540422,61624,235,236,540449,541715,541717])

b = {"Invoice":['581483','541431','573008','576236','546498','546498','546498','546498','536409'],
 "StockCode":['23843','23166','84077','22634','21523','48111','20685','48116','21326'],
 "Quantity":[80995,74215,4800,1,1,1,1,1,12],
 'CustomerID':[16446,12346,12901,13755,15493,15493,15493,15493,17908]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=b, index=[540421,61619,421632,465502,118799,118801,118802,118804,518])
```

Comment: приведите тестовый текстовый образец данных и напишите, что вы собираетесь с этим делать дальше, может проще сделать объединение по индексам?

Comment: Изначальная задача стоит так: для всех ли строк из первой таблицы найдутся строки во второй таблице, удовлетворяющие данным условиям

Comment: Делать итерацию в `pandas` плохой тон. Навскидку могу предложить сделать `merge` по **CustomerID** и **StockCode**, затем фильтр по тому что смерджилось и вывести индексы. С образцом данных проще дать ответ.

Comment: Подскажите, как я могу передать сюда в чат примеры этих таблиц?

Comment: сделать небольшую нарезку важных данных и разместить код, создающий два датафрейма

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пока нет образца данных, напишу такой лобовой вариант

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,5,3,], 'b':[4,7,6,]})

df1['present'] = df1.set_index(['a', 'b']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['a', 'b']).index)
print(df1)
print(df1.present.all())
```

результат

```
   a  b  present
0  1  4     True
1  2  5    False
2  3  6     True

False
```

Comment: А вот подготовил срез данных:

Comment: вы пробовали этот код? что-то не так?

Comment: Извините, но я не пойму, где в Вашем коде проверка условий? Мне нужно именно чтобы условия проверялись

Comment: `df1.set_index(['a', 'b']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['a', 'b']).index).all()` - собственно, True или False - *для всех ли строк из первой таблицы найдутся строки во второй таблице, удовлетворяющие данным условиям*

Comment: Это круто! я кое-как смог разобраться в логике Вашего кода. Спасибо Вам! Действительно сработало. Тогда усложню задачу и приведу полный текст условия. Третье условие тоже должно быть проверено. Дописал его в изначальном сообщении.